# Do any features of Firebase Cloud messaging require a Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm thinking about implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging without implementing a firebase database and it's unclear to me which features of FCM are supported without having a firebase database.

For instance, getting message delivery statistics (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery) and sending notifications via the firebase console (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-with-console). It doesn't explicitly say whether you need a firebase database in either of documents but I'd like to clear about that before implementing it.

So my question is, do you need a firebase database to send notifications via the firebase console or to view message delivery statistics? I know for the latter you need to implement google analytics. And also as a bonus, are there any firebase features that depend on having a firebase database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All FCM features are supported without having to use Realtime Database.  They are completely separate products, and are only related as much as you want them to be in your app.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wanted to double check